# Entity Framework Plus - FutureValue() in a foreach loop

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus

Recently I started using [EF+](https://entityframework-plus.net/) on our project with great success however sometimes I run into an issue that I have a set of entities for which I need to run a separate query.

So if I have a set of 20 customers I need to run 20 queries separately. I wonder if there is way how to avoid this using EF+ FutureValue() somehow in a foreach loop.

See this sample code:

```
foreach (var customer in customers)
                {
                    customer.SomeValue = ctx.SomeDatabaseTable.Where(myCondition).FutureValue();
                    // this would run 20 times ... any way how to run all of the 20 queries at once?
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to generate all "QueryFuture" queries then you can use them.

So two loop should make it works.

```
var futureQueries = new List<BaseQueryFuture>();

// create all query futures
for(int i = 0; i < customers.Length; i++)
{
    futureQueries.Add(ctx.SomeDatabaseTable.Where(myCondition).FutureValue());
}

// assign result (the first solved will make the call to the DB)
for(int i = 0; i < customers.Length; i++)
{
     customer.SomeValue = ((QueryFutureValue<SomeValueType>)futureQueries[i]).Value;
}
```