# Entity Framework Plus - Future() in a foreach loop

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus

My question is very similar to [Entity Framework Plus - FutureValue() in a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53334642).

I have this code:

```
public class CustomerService
{
    private readonly EntityContext Context = new EntityContext();
    
    private IQueryable<Customer> MakeQuery(object query)
    {
        return this.Context.Customers
            // Omitted more logic here to create a complex query.
            .AsQueryable();
    }

    public List<List<Customer>> GetCustomersBulk(List<object> queries)
    {
        var response = new List<List<Customer>>();
        var futureQueries = new List<QueryFutureEnumerable<Customer>>();

        foreach (var query in queries)
        {
            futureQueries.Add(
                this.MakeQuery(query: query)
                    .Future()
            );
        }
                                                
        foreach (var futureQuery in futureQueries)
        {
            response.Add(futureQuery.ToList());
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Fully working Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vg8pjA

However, using `Futures` seems to be actually slower than not using them.

If I try to use [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53339550) from the related question, as in using `FutureValue`, my query will only return 1 Customer rather than many of them. I think with that code, the queries are run in one DB trip but the result isn't what I want.

I tried to use `.FutureValue<IEnumerable<Customer>>()` but then I get this error:

```
Error   CS1929  'IQueryable<Customer>' does not contain a definition for 'FutureValue' and the best extension method overload 'QueryFutureExtensions.FutureValue<IEnumerable<Customer>>(IQueryable<IEnumerable<Customer>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<IEnumerable<Customer>>'
```

Note I am using `Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore` version `2.0.60`.

Comment: FutureValue doesn't work like this, this is for single value. Why do you believe this is slower? It's possible your query have some client-side evaluation (EF Core 2.x) which slow down the whole process?